# Creating dask_jobqueue schedulers to launch on a custom HPC

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I'm new to dask and trying to use it in our cluster which uses NC job scheduler (from Runtime Design Automation, similar to LSF). I'm trying to create an NCCluster class similar to LSFCluster to keep things simple.

What are the steps involved in creating a job scheduler for custom clusters?
Is there any other way to interface dask to custom clusters without using JobQueueCluster?

I could find info on how to use the LSFCluster/PBSCluster/..., but couldn't find much information on creating one for a different HPC.

Any links to material/examples/docs will help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working after going through the source code.
Tips for anyone trying:

- Create a customCluster & customJob class similar to LSFCluster & LSFJob.
- Override the following

  - submit_command
  - cancel_command
  - config_name (you'll have to define it in the jobqueue.yaml)
  - Depending on the cluster, you may need to override the _submit_job, _job_id_from_submit_ouput and other functions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019-10-14 there is no documentation on how to make a new cluster manager for dask-jobqueue.  That being said, the source code is not bad.  I encourage you to engage on the GitHub issue tracker.  https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/issues/new